# Transform:scale issue

Tags: css, transform

I have a div and im trying to scale it(just the Y) on hover.The problem is that it works well without transition.When i use transition,the div scales at top a bit and then goes down,check the fiddle.The question is how to prevent div from scalling like that?I want it to scale straight down,without this bouncing to top.
http://jsfiddle.net/q9akawr6/21/

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transition:.2s;
}
div:hover
{
  transition:.2s;
  transform-origin:top;
  transform:scaleY(2.0);
}
```

Comment: Be specific in your `transition: transform 0.2s linear;` Because right now it's also transitioning `transform-origin` from its initial value (`50% 50%`) to the new one (`50% 0%`) hence the "bounce".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Niet says, or just put this in the `div{}` rule, rather than `div:hover{}`:

```
transition:.2s;
transform-origin:top;
```

for the same reason (to avoid a transition on transform-origin at the wrong time).

Comment: this will work, you always have to keep only the modified rules in the affected states. If you specify transform-origin or transition in the hover, it has to recalculate it when you are hovering, causing issues like this bouncing effect.

Answer (score 0):

the div bouncing due to you margin area. I try to change your code. check the following

> HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="demo"></div>

</div>
```

> CSS:

```
div.container
{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
div.demo{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color:red;
  transition:.2s;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
div.demo:hover
{
  transition:all .2s linear;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform:scaleY(2.0);
}
```